# In HTML5, is it better to use <section> and <h1> instead of <h2>–<h6>?

Tags: html

In studying up on HTML5's new section tag, I'm wondering about the handling of h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, and h6 tags...

The HTML5 specification says that "[h1, h2, etc.] elements represent headings for *their sections*" (http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-h1-h2-h3-h4-h5-and-h6-elements). Further in the spec's "4.4.11 Headings and sections" section, there are currently three examples of structuring a document about apples.

If we follow the first specification, which states that heading elements "should represent headings for their sections," it seems the third apple example is the *most* correct structure (i.e., using h1 tags for the heading in each section and subsection). Using this logic it seems that the h2, h3, h4, h5, and h6 tags would be used rarely, if at all.

This is what I'm wondering: should h2, h3, h4, h5, or h6 tags really be used if, in reality, they are basically marking up subsections? Does it not make more sense to use section tags to separate sections, each with their own header, rather than relying on h2, h3, etc. to start implicit sections? (The "Headers and sections" section also talks about the sections implied by using h2, h3, etc.)

Perhaps it's my relational database knowledge causing a bias, but creating multiple header tags with numbers (h **1**, h **2**, h **3**) seems like bad practice, when technically they are each heading their own section or subsection.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: I'd like to see a <h>Heading Tag</h>

Comment: The document outline algorithm is a fiction. It has never been implemented by browsers or assistive technologies — if you use the h1-only approach, nothing will interpret it correctly. See https://codepen.io/stevef/post/a-decade-of-heading-backwards, (longer) https://adrianroselli.com/2016/08/there-is-no-document-outline-algorithm.html, and (even longer) https://css-tricks.com/document-outline-dilemma/.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that the spec even states that h1 has preference over all the others:

> Sections may contain headings of any rank, but authors are strongly encouraged to either use only h1 elements, or to use elements of the appropriate rank for the section's nesting level.

What disturbs me however is this:

> Authors are also encouraged to explicitly wrap sections in elements of sectioning content, instead of relying on the implicit sections generated by having multiple headings in one element of sectioning content.

Now it is wonderful that we got section, article, nav and aside to use to prevent div-itis. But if we need to explicitly use a section element for each section than we end up with more section elements then we ever had divs. I feel a strong case of section-itis coming on.

Comment: Div-itis doesn’t mean using lots of `<div>`s. It means using `<div>`s where another tag that has meaning would have been appropriate. Using `<section>` tags to mark up actual sections is just fine.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Robert. It sounds to me like a case for an "h" tag for use within sections, or h1..n tags for implied sections. Allowing hn in a section is just redundant.

Comment: Right, but there’s a bunch of browsers and screen readers and search engines and existing code that’s never heard of `<h>`, but knows that `<h1>` to `<h6>` are headings. I think XHTML 2 defined an `<h>` element, but HTML5 uses existing tags and user-agent behaviour where possible.

Comment: I like the concept of an h tag. If it was up to me, the new header tag would have replaced all the h1, h2, etc. because each is simply the header of a section. Just for the sake of discussion...

Comment: to me it makes sense to have an <h> tag similar to <p>, I usually have more than 6 headings on a home page, so to me having a generic h tag seems reasonable

Answer (score 1):

There is an implied hierarchy when you use these tags.  h2 sections are below h1; h3 is below h2, etc.  They are sub-sections sub-sections.  I'm not sure why this causes a disconnect.  If you only ever have one level of sub-sections then you would only ever use h1.

I think what you are objecting to is the `<section>` tag can provide similar hierarchical functionality, but the `<section>` tag is new to HTML and (as is often the case) just because there is another way to do it does not mean the specification changes to break the old ways.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts. I understand how the h1, h2, etc. tags work, but was just wondering what people's thoughts were regarding using them along with the new section tag. Of course, there are many ways to accomplish the same thing. Of the "apple" examples in the spec mentioned in my OP, I tend to side with the third example. My reasoning being that for example, a subsection with and h2 tag is a section in and of itself with its own header. For example, when a ul is nested in a "parent" ul's li, we don't use ul2. So why do this with headers? (Just trying to get a little discussion :)

Comment: I meant "... a subsection with **an** h2 tag..."

Comment: @robert : totally agree -- using h tags with subsections makes no real sense and would fall under the category of bad code smell.  I guess the spec has to cover that case but it seems ill advised to me.

Answer (score 1):

This may just be my interpretation of the new specs, but... it seems to me that the `<h1>`-`<h6>` tags are starting to be relegated to the duty of typographical hierarchy rather than true sectioning tag.

whatwg.org does clearly specify that the section tag can start with an H1 tag, which kind of flies in the face of what I have come to know of SEO best practices- only defining one per page.

This leads me to believe that this is the direction html could be moving... `<section>` is the "machine" readable component for a section and the heading tags will be the human friendly element.