# Should a section start with a h1 or h2?

Tags: html

I have an HTML page that roughly looks like

```
<header>
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <h2>Subheader</h2>
</header>
<main>
    <section>
        <h1>Header</h1>
    </section>
</main>
```

Is it correct to start a section with a h1? or should it be a h2? Should the amount of h1 tags be limited to one on each page?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In HTML5, is it better to use <section> and <h1> instead of <h2>–<h6>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492810/in-html5-is-it-better-to-use-section-and-h1-instead-of-h2-h6)

Comment: This is an opinion-based question. You can start off with any valid child element you want.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I suggest you start with the H1 tag
the bigger the page title is
the better because it looks better,
you have a good knowledge of CSS
you can make very good titles
good works :)

Comment: `h1` is not just a bigger font, it has semantic meaning. Any of the `h1`-`h6` elements can be designed as you like with CSS.

Answer (score -2):

You can use up to H6, so there's no need to repeat H1. Well, actually it depends on the look you trying to achieve. Good luck!